# Swift JSON Crash with Nil

Tags: ios, json, swift

i have a problem.. i have an app that connects with a database with jSON, now the problem is that he cannot find the element in the response of the database.
This is the code :

```
 func uploadtoDB(){
    var SelectVehicle = save.stringForKey("SelectVehicleChoosed")

    if SelectVehicle == nil  {

        var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertView.title = "Submit Failed!"
        alertView.message = "Please Select the Vehicle"
        alertView.delegate = self
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertView.show()


    }else {

        var post:NSString = "vechicleNumber=\(SelectVehicle)"

        NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

        var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://saimobileapp.com/services/sai_service_history.php?")!

        var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
        var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )
        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postData
        request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


        var reponseError: NSError?
        var response: NSURLResponse?

        var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)

        if ( urlData != nil ) {
            let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

            NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

            if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
            {
                var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);
                println(responseData)
                var error: NSError?

                let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as! NSDictionary


                var serviceDate = ((jsonData as NSDictionary)["serviceHistory"] as! NSDictionary) ["serviceDate"] as! String
                var serviceType = ((jsonData as NSDictionary)["serviceHistory"] as! NSDictionary) ["serviceType"] as! String
                var kms = ((jsonData as NSDictionary)["serviceHistory"] as! NSDictionary) ["mileage"] as! String
                var serviceLocation = ((jsonData as NSDictionary)["serviceHistory"] as! NSDictionary) ["serviceLocation"] as! String


                var serviced:Void = save.setObject(serviceDate, forKey: "ServiceDateChoosed")
                var servicet:Void = save.setObject(serviceType, forKey: "ServiceTypeChoosed")
                var kmsc:Void = save.setObject(kms, forKey: "KmsChoosed")
                var servicel:Void = save.setObject(serviceLocation, forKey: "ServiceLocationChoosed")
                              save.synchronize()

                 TableView.reloadData()

            }
        } 
    }
}
```

and this is the response

```
{"serviceHistory":[{"id":"2","vehicleNumber":"mh03aw0001","mobileNumber":"9503322593","customerName":"samsun","serviceDate":"2012-06-02","serviceType":"Paid Service","mileage":"65","serviceState":"Maharashtra","serviceLocation":"Lower Parel","PUC":""}]}
```

the app crash in the line `var serviceDate = ((jsonData as NSDictionary)["serviceHistory"] as! NSDictionary) ["serviceDate"] as! String` with nil because i think he can't find the element.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Looking at your JSON, `(jsonData as NSDictionary)["serviceHistory"]` is an array, not a dictionary (it begins with a `[`, not a `{`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// serviceHistory is an Array
var serviceHistoryArray = jsonData["serviceHistory"] as! NSArray

// fetch the first item...
var serviceHistoryItem = serviceHistoryArray[0] as! NSDictionary
var serviceDate = serviceHistoryItem["serviceDate"]
var serviceType = serviceHistoryItem["serviceType"]
var kms = serviceHistoryItem["mileage"]
var serviceLocation = serviceHistoryItem["serviceLocation"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a side note: parsing JSON has become sort of a popular playground for swift developers, since it's a nuanced problem that can be difficult in strongly typed languages. A bunch of people have written libraries for addressing this 'swiftily', and there have been a lot of interesting discussions on the topic. Some examples:

- [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)
- [json-swift](https://github.com/owensd/json-swift)

and some discussions of the problem:

- [Efficient JSON in Swift with Functional Concepts and Generics](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/efficient-json-in-swift-with-functional-concepts-and-generics)
- [Parsing JSON in Swift](http://chris.eidhof.nl/posts/json-parsing-in-swift.html)